# DataFrame can not read dict correctly

Tags: pandas, dictionary, dataframe

i want read the dict with DataFrame,but the result is only read the columns no value has been read. why this happen?

```
In [65]: i        
Out[65]: 
{'Alias': 'S510994824',
 'AppAccountFlag': 0,
 'AttrStatus': 234337,
 'ChatRoomId': 0,
 'City': '武汉',
 ......
 ......
 ......
 'VerifyFlag': 0}

In [66]: DataFrame(i,columns=i.keys())
Out[66]: 
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [StarFriend, PYQuanPin, SnsFlag, HeadImgUrl, RemarkPYQuanPin, UniFriend, ContactFlag, RemarkName, AttrStatus, City, Uin, Alias, PYInitial, RemarkPYInitial, Statues, MemberCount, HideInputBarFlag, AppAccountFlag, EncryChatRoomId, VerifyFlag, Sex, Signature, DisplayName, MemberList, Province, OwnerUin, NickName, UserName, ChatRoomId, KeyWord]
Index: []

[0 rows x 30 columns]
```

why cannot read the values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For me works pass `index` parameter:

```
import pandas as pd

d = {'Alias': 'S510994824',
 'AppAccountFlag': 0,
 'AttrStatus': 234337,
 'ChatRoomId': 0,
 'City': '武汉',
 'VerifyFlag': 0}

df = pd.DataFrame(d, index=[0])
print (df)
        Alias  AppAccountFlag  AttrStatus  ChatRoomId City  VerifyFlag
0  S510994824               0      234337           0   武汉           0
```

Another solution is add `[]`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([d])
print (df)
        Alias  AppAccountFlag  AttrStatus  ChatRoomId City  VerifyFlag
0  S510994824               0      234337           0   武汉           0
```

And last solution with [`DataFrame.from_dict`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.from_dict.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d, orient='index')
#set column name
df.columns = ['col']
print (df)
                       col
VerifyFlag               0
Alias           S510994824
AttrStatus          234337
ChatRoomId               0
City                    武汉
AppAccountFlag           0
```